# "After insert on..." trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

```
create trigger nuevaVenta
after insert on Compra
if new.idProducto = Productos_Farmaceuticos.idProducto
        set Productos_Farmaceuticos.inventario = Productos_Farmaceuticos.invetario - new.cantProducto;
```

I am trying to update the amount of pieces in stock after a new sell is done, here are my tables:

```
Paciente: idPaciente, nombre
Compra: idProducto, idPaciente, fecha, cantProduct
Productos_Farmaceuticos: idProducto, nombreProduct, precioProduct, puntoReorden, inventario
```

Here is an update that shows no syntax errors:

```
delimiter //
create trigger nuevaVenta
after insert on medapp.Compra
for each row
begin
    if new.idProducto = Productos_Farmaceuticos.idProducto then
        update medapp.Productos_Farmaceuticos
        set Productos_Farmaceuticos.inventario = 
            Productos_Farmaceuticos.invetario - new.cantProduct;
    end if;
end; //
delimiter ;
```

but it now shows me an "Error code 1109: Unknown table 'Productos_Farmaceuticos' in field list" when I try to insert something in Compra

Comment: it just says "SQL syntax error near on Compra..."

Comment: You have `on compra` twice.  Try removing the first one. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: changed that, now the error is "SQL syntax near 'if new.idProducto...'"

Comment: execute  **select * from Productos_Farmaceuticos** If you got same error. It might be case sensitive issue.

Comment: It shows me no errors with "select * from Productos_Farmaceuticos"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is an error in this line:

```
end; //
```

You have changed the delimiter to '//'. Therefore, this line ought to read simply:

```
end //
```